# Having trouble with this FOL general induction argument.

Tags: first-order-logic

Suppose that if variable assignments $s_1, s_2$ agree on all free variables in $B$, then $M, s_1 \models B$ iff $M, s_2 \models B$. Show that if $s_1$ and $s_2$ agree on all free variables in $\forall x B$, and $M, s_1 \models \forall x B$, then $M s_2 \models \forall x B$.

Let $M, s_1 \models \forall x B$. This means that $M, s_1' \models B$ for every $x$-variant $s_1'$ of $s_1$. To show that $M, s_2 \models \forall x B$, let $s_2'$ be any $x$-variant of $s_2$. We WTS that $M, s_2' \models B$. Since $s_2'$ is an $x$-variant of $s_2$ and since  $M, s_1' \models B$ for every $x$-variant $s_1'$ of $s_1$ we can find some $s_1'$ for any $s_2'$ such that $M, s_1' \models B$ and that  $s_1'$ assigns the same thing to $x$ as does our $s_2'$.

Then the free variables of B are
among $x_1, . . . , x_n$ and x. Moreover, $ s_1' (x_i ) = s_2' (x_i),$ since $s_1', s_2'$ are $x$-variants of $s_1, s_2$  respectively and by the hypothesis $s_1(x_i) = s_2(x_i) $.  $ s_1' (x_i ) = s_2' (x_i),$ by the way we have defined $s_1'$. Then the induction hypothesis applies to B and $s _1', s_2'$, so
$M, s_2' \models B$. However, this x variant was chosen arbitrarily. Hence, for any $x$-variant of $s_2$  it satisfies $B,$ and so we have that $M, s_2 \models \forall x B$, but this is the desired result.

This Doesnt quite feel right, i think i have messed something up here. ( i know their is no base case here im just posting the inductive step i am having trouble with.)

Comment: It looks fine to me (apart from the abbreviation "WTS" which took me a second or two to decode). What is worrying you about it?

Comment: @RobArthan Well its one of those books where the majority of stuff to be proved is left to exercise which i actually prefer in more advanced classes. However in such a definition heavy class and as a first class (for me at least, most of the others have learned FOL in a phil class before this.) this is actually a main proposition in the book that is not proved and its the very first for all proof so it feels odd.  Anyway  $s_1(x_i) = s_2(x_i) $ this part worries me also the transition to the for all case seemed odd. This induction just looks weird i guess.

Comment: Perhaps a relevant point is that your inductive hypothesis about $B$ is strong: it applies to all $s_1$ and $s_2$ that agree on the free variables of $B$. It might also improve your write-up to state explicitly the assumption that $s_2$ agrees with $s_1$ on the free variables of $\forall x B$ towards the beginning of the proof.

Comment: It seems your self-aware unconfidence lies in the use of universal elim/intro inference rules together with induction hypothesis. Your given assumptions already say variable assignments $s_1$ and $s_2$ agree on *all* free variables in $B$ and $\forall x B$ in any structure $M$, so your induction is on the complexity of all the free variables $x_i$ or the two assignments? You may not need induction at all and thus no base case is totally fine, otherwise a base case is always *required* for any induction proof...